# Is there a way to identify whether "filtered" state in nmap output caused by a network or host-based firewall?

Tags: network, firewalls, nmap, network-scanners

Is there a way to identify whether "filtered" state for a specific port in nmap output is caused by a network firewall or host-based firewall?

Comment: ***No.*** We are ***not*** going to accept questions where an AI bot generates arbitrary text and we are asked to validate the text for correctness.

Comment: And please look up what "filtered" means from the nmap documentation. That will answer you.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't.

The reason you get "filtered" as a result is because nmap cannot communicate with the port (see [here](https://nmap.org/book/man-port-scanning-basics.html) for an explanation - section "filtered").

There can be many reasons why nmap cannot get a response from a port. Any device between your box and the target may cause this and there's no way to distinguish which has done it; it may be the target's host-based firewall or any other firewall in between your box and the target.

Unless, of course, you know the network path between your box and the target's, know all boxes in between and scan each one separately in order to find out who's blocking the communication.

Comment: I edited the question back to something more reasonable.